# Mudar o CSS com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Já mudei css com jQuery, mas eu gostaria de testar uma funcionalidade, no onclick ele adicionar um css, mas um campo `:before` como eu poderia fazer isso?

**Código funcionando**

```
$j("#nome-login-mobile").click(function(){
    if ($j('#options-menu').is(':visible')) {
        $j('#options-menu').hide();
        $j('.nome-login-mobile').removeClass('changed');
    } else {
        $j('.nome-login-mobile').toggleClass('changed');
        $j('#options-menu').show();
    }    
})
```

Comment: Da uma olhadinha básica aqui, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addClass`, ou `toggleClass` para tirar e por a cada click

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('before');
});
```

```css
div.before:before {
    content: "before adicionado ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>adicionar before</div>
```

Comment: Consegui, mas ele só volta ao normal quando eu clico 2x, como eu poderia dar um remove no meu if?

Comment: Vou atualizar a pergunta com o código.

Comment: poste o html também, não entendi o que quer fazer

Comment: Já consegui, atualizei a pergunta com o código a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Tem como você postar um exemplo de como quer?

acredito que algo como:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#efeito', function(){ //Ação executada no evento de clique no elemento com ID = "efeito"
$('#teste').css("background-color", "yellow"); //Insere fundo amarelo no elemento com ID = "teste"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste">xyz</div>
<a herf="#" id="efeito">Mudar Estilo</a>
```

Comment: É algo parecido com isso, só que eu tinha duvidas se dava para alterar as funções :after e :before, o jeito que achei foi adicionar uma class com um after e uma outra class com outro after, e no onclick alterar as classes para ter a mudança que eu gostaria.